# In JavaScript, how can I pass value from unnamed function to another unnamed function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, one of which checks if an image loads:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "xxx";
img.onload = function() {
    var dimensionValue = 'loaded';
};
img.onerror = function() {
    var dimensionValue = 'failed';
}
```

A subsequent function executes when a user clicks a button, like so:

```
var trackClick = function(url) {
  console.log(dimensionValue);
};
```

I am trying to log the value of `dimensionValue` at the point the `trackClick` function is called (from an `a` link). However, despite the first function succesfully printing  out the dimensionValue, when the second function is triggered it contains no value or it fails to indicate that `dimensionValue` does not exist.

I have also attempted to place the `trackClick` within the `onload`/`onerror` functions, but then a message displays informing that there is no function called `trackClick`

So, my question is how to pass a value from one unnamed function to another anonymous function in JS?

Comment: Create a variable that is accessible by `trackClick`, `onload` and `onerror` and assign the value to that variable. In other words, the variable must be defined outside of `trackClick`, `onload` and `onerror`.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable might not be able to be accessed by the other function because it is defined in another function.

Try:

```
var dimensionValue;
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "xxx";
img.onload = function() {
    dimensionValue = 'loaded';
};
img.onerror = function() {
    dimensionValue = 'failed';
}
```

I think you could also do:

```
var trackClick = function(url) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "xxx";
    img.onload = function() {
        console.log('loaded');
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, please post all of your code for further assistance.

Comment: This won't work.  By redeclaring `dimensionValue` inside those two functions, you are scoping that variable to its function and will never change the top-level `dimensionValue`.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `dimensionValue` outside of your functions, you widen the scope that can access it.  Assuming your `trackClick` function is in the same scope, it should have access to `dimensionValue`.

```
var dimensionValue
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "xxx";
img.onload = function() {
    dimensionValue = 'loaded';
};
img.onerror = function() {
    dimensionValue = 'failed';
}
```